# PCA Interpretation

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, machine-learning, principal-component-analysis

The problem formulation is to show that PCA involves choosing a vector u, so as to minimize the sum of the squares of the projection errors(of the training examples x onto u),subject to u'*u=1
x(i) = R mx1 , u is a vector 
I.e minimize sum over i, Norm square of(projection of x(i) - x(i)) subject to u'*u=1

How do i represent the projection of x(i) onto the vector u and formulate the lagrangian?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $u$ is a vector of norm 1 (i.e. $u'u = 1$) then the projection of $x(i)$ on $u$ is the vector $\langle x(i),u\rangle u$ with $\langle x(i),u\rangle$ the scalar product of the two vectors.

The PCA consists in minimizing the error, as you said, $$\sum_i \|x(i)-\langle x(i),u\rangle u\|^2, $$ or equivalently 
$$\text{maximize }\sum_i \langle x(i), u\rangle^2$$
This can be solved, not using the Lagrangian but the following matrix formulation. If $X$ is the matrix of row $x(i)$, then the problem is to
$$\text{maximize }\| Xu\|^2$$
which is a simple eigenvalue problem...

Comment: Hi can you kindly explain why the two are equivalent?

Comment: P.s nvm i got it.Can we not formulate the lagrangian for the first objective function and solve it?

Comment: @Sridhar : he forgot to say that all the time we consider the constraint that the vectors $u_1,ldots,u_k$ are orthonormal (if we forget this constraint, maximize $\sum_k \|Xu_k\|^2$ subject to $\|u_k\|^2=1$ gives $u_k = u_1$ the eigenvector associated to the greatest eigenvalue)

Comment: @SridharThiagarajan : that's why we write $$\max_U \quad trace(U^T X^T X U)$$ subject to $U^T U = I_k$ which gives the lagragian $\mathcal{L}(U,\lambda) =  \sum_k u_k^T X^T X u_k + \sum_{ij} \lambda_{ij} (u_i^T u_j - \delta_{ij})$ and $\displaystyle \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial u_k} =0 $ tells you that the $u_k$ are eigenvectors of $X^T X$